# Detect that the application at Delphi under iOS was deactivated

Tags: ios, delphi

do you have anyone idea how to detect under iOS at the Delphi application that the application was deactivated and user switched to some other application?

I tested the events onClode, onDectivate (which should be most logical one), onHide, but none of them gives the result.

The problem I have is that my application uses MIDI and because if that it needs to have allowed to use background music and when user leaves the app, it's still paying the sound.

Comment: I don't work with iOS, but it seems to me the most logical ones would be `OnActivate` and `OnDeactive` for some reason. It works in Windows and Android.

Comment: See http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/FMX.Platform.TApplicationEvent

Comment: That should be logical, but doesn't work .. I found this https://forums.embarcadero.com/message.jspa?messageID=537131 - but I'm not sure which version of Delphi it's

Comment: hmmm, on top you can read "firemonkey, ios, xe2"

Comment: There are some ugly parts in that `TSubjectMessageiOS`: 1. `Create(AOwner:TComponent)` -> copypaste error 2. Global variable `SubjectMessageiOS` - better use a function that contains the code from `initialization` part

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to make it a workable component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the IFMXApplicationEventService.
This a sample http://blogs.embarcadero.com/pawelglowacki/2013/09/30/40067